# How do you install a granite counter top as a floating shelf on a cement wall?

Tags: bathroom, kitchens, kitchen-counters, granite, countertops

Here is a picture of the space, I want to install a vessel sink and a granite counter top. I would like to install it as a floating shelf and later add in the cabinets as I don't have them at the moment. Or Maybe if it's possible to build cabinets using basic tools, id like to do that as well. I have a similar situation in the kitchen.

I'm in Ecuador by the way.

[image]
[image]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: how do you install the counter top as a floating shelf on a cement wall

Comment: Mostly, you don't. You put the cabinets in first, since it is the cabinets that support the countertop. You can try to install it the same way you would a shelf, but you will likely have to remove it completely when you decide to put cabinets in.

Comment: Well on the smaller bathroom i do plan to do a floating shelf with a vessel sink and no storage. Just triangular side support and a shelf under it. What kind of support do you need? How do you do it? the wall is also cement with tile on it

Answer (score 1):

Bottom line is you can't "float" it - you need to rest it on something. Countertop-thickness Granite has no strength across a span of more than a few inches.

Steel rods are often added to granite countertops to help support around dishwashers and sinks, and in those situations the granite is well supported by the cabinets itself. In your case you'd need a lot more.

If you want to do this, then what you need to do is effectively build an inset floating shelf across that opening, and then you can place the granite on that.

I would attach 2x4s level along the 3 walls using concrete anchors, and then I'd laminate together several 2 or 3 2x4s to make the front support. I'd put cross-braces the whole way (i.e., like a ladder). Obviously don't put cross supports where they will interfere with the sink, but make sure you have supports very close to the sink.

Make sure the shelf is sturdy with absolutely zero flex.

Nothing about this would be temporary.

Bottom line is nothing can flex, and the granite must not be more than a few inches from something support it (i.e., a little metal angle bracket won't be enough).

Comment: thanks for the reply. I suppose in the two above pictures ill have to find a way to get cabinets first in order to make it work.But in the smaller bathroom i could probably float it, i've seen a few bathrooms do it here. Ill add a picture of the smaller bathroom later so that it makes more sense.